# Drawing a child window on top of another child window?

Tags: c++, winapi

I have different screens serving different purposes in my win32 app, each screen having a different background. The main window have its own static background.
I am drawing screen background on a custom window using following code.

```
panelBackground = LoadBitmap ( hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE ( bitmap ) );

WNDCLASSEX wincl;

wincl.hInstance         = hInstance;
wincl.lpszClassName     = "jPanel";
wincl.lpfnWndProc       = WndProc;
wincl.style             = CS_BYTEALIGNWINDOW;// | CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
wincl.cbSize            = sizeof (WNDCLASSEX);
wincl.hIcon             = 0;
wincl.hIconSm           = 0;
wincl.hCursor           = LoadCursor (NULL, IDC_ARROW);
wincl.lpszMenuName      = NULL;
wincl.cbClsExtra        = 0;
wincl.cbWndExtra        = 4;
wincl.hbrBackground     = ( HBRUSH ) GetStockObject( BLACK_BRUSH );

RegisterClassEx (&wincl);

hwnd = CreateWindowEx ( 0, "jPanel", txt.c_str(), WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_CHILD, x, y, width, height, parent, 0, hInstance, 0) ;

SetWindowLong( hwnd , 0 , ( LONG ) this ) ;

SetWindowPos ( hwnd , HWND_BOTTOM, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOMOVE ) ;
```

Then in the WndProc :

```
view::jPanel* panel = ( view::jPanel* ) GetWindowLong( hwnd , 0 ) ;

case WM_PAINT:
  {
     if ( ! panel )
        return 0 ;

     HDC hdc ;
     PAINTSTRUCT ps ;
     RECT rect ;

     GetClientRect( hwnd , &rect ) ;

      hdc = BeginPaint( hwnd , &ps ) ;


         HDC dcSkin = CreateCompatibleDC ( hdc );                               // memory dc for skin

         HDC hMemDc = CreateCompatibleDC ( hdc );                               // memory dc for painting


         HBITMAP hmemBmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap ( hdc, rect.right - rect.left, rect.bottom - rect.top  );     // Create bitmap to draw on


         HBITMAP hOldMemBmp = (HBITMAP)SelectObject ( hMemDc, hmemBmp );        // select memory bitmap in memory dc

         HBITMAP hOldSkinBmp = (HBITMAP)SelectObject ( dcSkin, panel->panelBackground );    //select skin bitmap in skin memory dc


            BitBlt ( hMemDc, 0, 0, rect.right - rect.left, rect.bottom - rect.top, dcSkin, 0, 0, SRCCOPY );     // Paint Skin on Memory DC
            BitBlt ( hdc, 0, 0, rect.right - rect.left, rect.bottom - rect.top, hMemDc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY );            // Paint Skin on Window DC


         //<<<... DeleteDC will leak memory if it holds a resource, so lets select the old bitmap back in the memory DCs
         SelectObject ( hMemDc, hOldMemBmp );                                   // select old bitmaps back to their respective DCs before deleting
         SelectObject ( dcSkin, hOldSkinBmp );                                  // select old bitmaps back to their respective DCs before deleting


         DeleteObject ( hOldSkinBmp );
         DeleteObject ( hOldMemBmp );
         DeleteObject(  hmemBmp );
         DeleteDC ( hMemDc );
         DeleteDC ( dcSkin );


      EndPaint( hwnd , &ps ) ;
  }
  break ;
```

**Problem :** The child windows(buttons, edit controls) belonging to that screen don't show up, I am guessing 
that they are below the screen background window. Moving the controls up the z-order with WS_EX_TOPMOST style doesn't work neither moving the screen background window at the bottom of z-order with SetWindowPos ( hwnd , HWND_BOTTOM, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOMOVE ) ; works.

And yes buttons are BS_BITMAP styled.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `WS_CLIPCHILDREN` style when you create the parent window.

Comment: Yes I did, the Screen background window is not the parent of buttons and edits, its their sibling, and the parent of them all has the WS_CLIPCHILDREN style.